# Typescript changed property type?

Tags: angular, typescript, router

I faced some weird problem. I have a class:

```
export class Example: {
    str: string;
    isActive: boolean;
}
```

Then I transfer some data of that class from one component to another via `routerLink` and `queryParams`... At the child component I'm doing this:

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Example) => {
            console.log(params, typeof params.isActive); //outputs string!!
        });

//output: {str: "xxx", isActive: "true"}, "string"
```

First I sent queryParams in template as:

`[routerLink]="['/my/route', row]"`,

then I tried to do it in a controller:

```
onBtnClick(row: Example) {
    console.log(row, typeof row.isActive);
    this.router.navigate(['/my/route'],{queryParams: row});
}
//output: {str: "xxx", isActive: true}, "boolean"
```

Why is it happen and how to fix this?

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: How did boolean property `isActive` become `string`??

Answer (score 1):

Because the parameters you pass at

```
this.router.navigate(['/my/route'],{queryParams: row});
```

goes to [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). In any case it is gonna be string.

You have 2 options:

Don't use router params to pass your data. Instead, use a service. Thus, you will keep your original JSON data.

or

Remap the transferred data to your object type.